# Index text files word by word in Python

Tags: python, indexing

So I have to compress/encode large text files by replacing the words with index numbers starting with 1 instead of 0. Here is a short example:

This is an amazing "abstract" AND this: is the end of this amazing abstract.

must be compressed/encoded as:

1 2 3 4 "5" 6 7: 2 8 9 10 7 4 5.

I wrote this code to read the large files line by line and to split the words in each line into elements of a list:

```
input_file = open("example.txt", "r")

for line in input_file:
    wordlist = line.split()
    print(wordlist)
```

However, I really do not know how to pair the words to a number like in the example. I also have to add that I'm a newbie to programming, so sorry if I use the wrong terminology or for explaining this badly. I am really stuck with this so any help is very greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to map words to numbers `{'This': 1, 'is': 2, ...}`

```
numbers = {}
output = ''
current_word = ''
for char in input_str:
    if char.isalpha():
        current_word += char
    else:
        if current_word:
            if current_word not in numbers:
                numbers[current_word] = len(numbers) + 1
            output += str(numbers[current_word])
        output += char
        current_word = ''
```